# Random string of characters when outputting to file in C

Tags: c, scheduling

I am writing a First Come First Served Scheduling Algorithm. I believe I have the right algorithm down and am processing jobs in the correct order and time for my list of processes. Only problem I have is with how it's being output to my output file. Every other job name is being output right with the exception of the first job on the list.

Here is my header file: **fcfs.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H
#define FUNCTION_H

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// STRUCTURE THAT HOLDS CPU INFORMATION                                     |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Struct that simulates the cpu running, cpu1 being the cpu currently running
// tells what the clock pulse is, its current job, and whether or not it is 
// occupied
struct cpu
{
    int clock_pulse;
    struct processes* job;
    bool occupied;
}cpu1 = {0, NULL, false};


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTIONS FOR CPU                                                        |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void increment_clock_pulse(); // increments clock_pulse by 1

bool is_cpu_occupied(); // returns true if cpu is occupied, false otherwise

void check_arrivals(); // changes cpu1 state and waiting queue

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// STRUCTURE THAT HOLDS INFORMATION FOR PROCESS QUEUE                       |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Structure that holds individual nodes for each process in the waiting
// queue. Holds process name, arrival time, service time, priority level
struct processes
{
    char name[10];
    int arrival_time;
    int service_time;
    int priority_level;
    struct processes *next;
};

struct processes *head = NULL; // instance of processes that points to beginning

struct processes *rear = NULL; // instance of processes that points to end

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BASIC FUNCTIONS FOR LINKED LIST QUEUE                                    |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void enqueue(char *n, int a, int s, int p); // places process at the back of the queue

void dequeue(); // removes the front of the queue

void print_list(); // prints out the list of processes

bool is_empty(); // returns true if empty, false if not

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTION FOR READING FILE INTO QUEUE                                     |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fill_array(char *file); // fills in the queue from file input

void output(); // outputs the jobs into output.txt, creates it if it doesn't exist

#endif
```

Here is my implementation file: **fcfs.c**

```
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "fcfs.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTIONS FOR CPU                                                        |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// increments the clock pulse by one
void increment_clock_pulse()
{
    cpu1.clock_pulse++;
}

// returns true if cpu is occupied, false if not
bool is_cpu_occupied()
{
    return cpu1.occupied;
}

// checks the queue if there are jobs ready to be serviced
void check_arrivals()
{
    // if job is ready to be serviced and if there is not already a job in the CPU
    if(head->arrival_time <= cpu1.clock_pulse && !cpu1.occupied)
    {
        cpu1.occupied = true; // changes the CPU to occupied 
        cpu1.job = head;      // gives the CPU the next job
        dequeue();            // dispatches the previous job from the queue
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BASIC FUNCTIONS FOR LINKED LIST QUEUE                                    |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

 // Funtcion the takes in a string and 3 integers for its input
 // and inserts the data into the queue
 void enqueue(char *n, int a, int s, int p)
 {
     struct processes *temp = (struct processes*)malloc(sizeof(struct processes));
     strcpy(temp->name, n);
     temp->arrival_time = a;
     temp->service_time = s;
     temp->priority_level = p;
     temp->next = NULL;
     if(head == NULL && rear == NULL){
        head = rear = temp;
        return;
     }
     rear->next = temp;
     rear = temp;
 }

 // Function that dequeues the first item in the queue and then moves the 
 // queue forward
 void dequeue()
 {
     struct processes* temp = head;
     if(head == NULL) {
        printf("Queue is Empty\n");
        return;
     }
     if(head == rear) {
        head = rear = NULL;
     }
     else {
        head = head->next;
     }
     free(temp);
 }

// Function that prints out the current queue
void print_list()
{
    struct processes *ptr = head;
    printf("\n[ ");

    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("(%s %d %d %d) ",ptr->name, ptr->arrival_time, 
                ptr->service_time, ptr->priority_level);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    printf(" ]");
}

// Returns true if the queue is empty, false if it is not
bool is_empty()
{
    return head == NULL;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTION FOR READING FILE INTO QUEUE                                     |
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Function that fills in the queue, takes in an argument that is the 
// name of the file that contains the processes
void fill_array(char *file)
{
    FILE *fp;   // File pointer
    fp = fopen(file, "r");   // opens the file to read processes

    // checks to see whether or not fopen() is successful
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    // reads in data until End of File
    int a, s, p;
    char n[10];
    while(feof(fp)==0)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d", n, &a, &s, &p);

        enqueue(n, a, s, p);
     }

     fclose(fp);
 }

void output()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("output.txt", "a");

    fprintf(fp, "%s %d %d \n", cpu1.job->name, (cpu1.clock_pulse - cpu1.job->arrival_time), cpu1.clock_pulse);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

And my driver file: **main.c**

```
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "fcfs.c"

int main()
{
    char file[20]; // buffer for file name

    printf("Please enter your file name: "); // prompts user for file name
    scanf("%s", file);

    fill_array(file); // fills array from file

    // Beginning of the FCFS Algorithm
    while(!is_empty())
    {
        if(cpu1.occupied)   // If CPU is busy 
        {
            if(cpu1.job->service_time == 0) // If current job in CPU is done CPU changes to not busy
            {
                output();               // outputs job to file when job is finished
                cpu1.occupied = false;  
            }
        }

        check_arrivals(); // checks for arrivals in the waiting queue

        if(cpu1.occupied) // If the CPU is occupied job is not done
        {
            cpu1.job->service_time--; // decrement service time of current job
        }

        increment_clock_pulse(); // increment the clock pulse
     }


     return 0;
}
```

This is my input file: **processes.txt**

```
A0 6 15 4 
A1 9 40 6 
A2 9 12 9 
A3 12 15 4 
A4 30 11 2 
A5 45 70 1 
A6 70 23 9 
A7 75 23 5 
A8 75 18 7 
A9 90 5 6
```

And the output: **output.txt**

```
¢ 15 21 
A1 52 61 
A2 64 73 
A3 76 88 
A4 69 99 
A5 124 169 
A6 122 192 
A7 140 215 
A8 158 233
A9 148 238
```

Each time I run it I get a different string of characters for the first process that gets written in, in this case A0.

My thinking is that I'm passing them from the queue to the cpu wrong and it's giving me jumbled up garbage.

I've searched all over and can't find an answer anywhere. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a big problem here, and given the symptoms it's very likely to be related:

```
// checks the queue if there are jobs ready to be serviced
void check_arrivals()
{
    // if job is ready to be serviced and if there is not already a job in the CPU
    if(head->arrival_time <= cpu1.clock_pulse && !cpu1.occupied)
    {
        cpu1.occupied = true; // changes the CPU to occupied 
        cpu1.job = head;      // gives the CPU the next job
        dequeue();            // dispatches the previous job from the queue
    }
}
```

you store the value of `head` and then you call `dequeue()` which deletes `head` memory.
`cpu1.job` now points to unallocated memory => undefined behaviour

Still, the program "almost" runs fine, so it's just a problem of memory ownership.
I would suggest to change your `cpu` data structure to be able to hold the memory of the job as follows (no more pointer on `job`):

```
struct cpu
{
    int clock_pulse;
    bool occupied;
    struct processes job;
}cpu1 = {0, false, {"",0,0,0,NULL} };
```

Then change this code (and all the code where `job->` is now `job.`)

```
    if(head->arrival_time <= cpu1.clock_pulse && !cpu1.occupied)
    {
        cpu1.occupied = true; // changes the CPU to occupied 
        cpu1.job = *head;      // gives the CPU the next job
        dequeue();            // dispatches the previous job from the queue
    }
```

so `head` is copied before being deallocated. You keep the memory safe in that case.

Comment: Tried that approach. Two things happened. A0 was not written to the file, then afterwards the program crashed before finishing. I think the problem is with the dequeuing it first, once it gets to the last job it's trying  to dequeue nothing? Thanks for the quick response though, gave me an idea of how I could fix it. I'll report back if I do.

Comment: I propose another approach. Should work, since yours almost worked.